redis get all keys is too slow and takes more than one second
I have a 2 jobs that get keys from redis every second but it takes more than 1 sec for every job and its too slow for me.
How can i get my all redis keys under 1 second
My records should be 5000 eventually
    $redis = Redis::connection('report-db');
    $scanResult = [];

    $cursor = 0;

    do {
        $result = $redis->scan($cursor);
        $cursor = $result[0];
        $scanResult = array_merge($scanResult, $result[1]);
    } while ($cursor != 0);

    $pipe = $redis->pipeline();
    foreach ($scanResult as $key) {
        $pipe->get($key);
    }

    $results = $pipe->execute();

    $accounts = collect($results)->map(function ($value) {
        return json_decode($value);
    });

this is my code in my job to get all my redis keys

I believe scan() is the culprit here. Maybe try to assemble the keys like this: $keys = $redis->keys('*'); then change foreach ($scanResult as $key) to foreach ($keys as $key).

Be aware that using the KEYS command in Redis blocks the main thread in Redis an prevents any other operations from running. Also, both KEYS and SCAN are O(N) where N is the number of keys in Redis. Both commands must look at every key in Redis and see if it matches the provided pattern.
